# Shopify Gem: Is there a way to retrieve the industry and experience level for a store?

Tags: shopify

When a storeowner sets up a store on Shopify, they have to enter their industry and experience level. Is there a way to retrieve those values using the ShopifyAPI gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this information is not available through the API.